# run through a loop and then reset and run it again

Tags: javascript, loops, increment

I want to change an image to image"i" until I run out of images, then I want to start from the beginning again.

This is what I need to do

- Run the following code until *i >= n*
- Then reset i to zero

Code:

```
  function advanceSlide()
  {
    i++;
    currentIMG ='"image"+i';
    changeBG(currentIMG);
  }
```

This is what I have so far, I am only confused by resting *i* when the loop is done:

```
  window.setInterval(function(){
    advanceSlide();
    }, 5000);

  function advanceSlide(){
    while (i<n){
      i++;
      currentIMG='"Image"+i';
      changeBG(currentIMG);
    }
  };
```

That covers what I need to do when *i < n*, so how do I tell it what to do when *i **is not less than**  n*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a global `imgIndex`

```
imgIndex = 0;
noOfImages = 10;

function advanceSlide(){
  imgIndex++;
  if( imgIndex >= noOfImages ) { imgIndex = 0; }
  currentIMG = "Image" + imgIndex;
  changeBG(currentIMG);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to wrap `advanceSlide` inside a function. You can use modulo to get reset i

```
window.setInterval(advanceSlide, 5000);
function advanceSlide(){    
    i = (i+1)%n;
    currentIMG="Image"+i;
    changeBG(currentIMG);   
}
```

Comment: made the upvote since this is neatest answer even if other was accepted..  and now I'm deleting my comments so don't confuse anyone else finding this Q in future... sorry

Answer (score 0):

Please make your question clearer next time.

```
int i = 0;
while (true){
        i++;
        if (i<n){
           currentIMG='"Image"+i';
           changeBG(currentIMG);
        }
        else
        {
           i = 0;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When i >= n then it'll simply exit the loop and continue with whatever code you put after the while() { }

with your set interval, there's no need for a closure there since it's only calling one other function, can be simplified to `window.setInterval(advanceSlide, 5000);`

You could also replace that while loop with a for loop since you're just incrementing an index

```
window.setInterval(advanceSlide, 5000);

function advanceSlide() {
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        // also here don't really need to store in a variable just pass straight in
        changeBG("Image" + i)
    }
}
```

I'm assuming for this answer that your Interval is how you want to recall the function...  Another answer here shows using a while(1) loop with your other loop inside for a way to loop over and over without the timer